# CSS negative margins, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a 1 column flexible / 1 column fixed layout. 'col-a' should be flexible, taking up 100% - 110px, 'col-b' should be fixed and aligned right.

I' trying to use negative margins but having little luck.

```
<div class="cont">

    <div class="col-a">
    Be flexible 
    </div>

    <div class="col-b">
    Be fixed
    </div>

</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

.cont {
background-color: #00f;
padding: 10px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.col-a {
background-color: #0ff;
padding-right: 110px;
margin-right: -110px;
float: left;
}

.col-b {
background-color: #ff0;
width: 110px;
float: left;
}
```

Can it be done using just this mark-up?
/*Answer found */
Here is the solution

```
.cont {
  background-color: #00f;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col-a {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0ff;
  margin-right: -110px;
  float: left;
}

.col-b {
  background-color: #ff0;
  width: 110px;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: What is your CSS? Also, have you tried any other approaches/css?

Comment: Please share the css, and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Is that what you want to do ? http://jsfiddle.net/pboissonneault/gyzkY/

Comment: @Philippe Boissonneault yes, that is exactly what I have been trying to do,  width:100% was the key. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a negative margin for this.

This is how I would set it up.

1. Set your column parent container to position relative.
2. Set your column A to have a padding-right of 110px (to make space for Column B)
3. Set your column B to be absolutely positioned to the top, right with a fixed width of 110px.

This will allow your Column A to expand 100% horizontally, while leaving space on the right for Column B.

Here's an example of what I outlined above: http://jsfiddle.net/NPn8d/

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but my 'cont' container needs to stretch as either col fills up.

Comment: Any particular reason why you need the parent 'cont' to stretch vertically?

If it's for background purposes, you can just set it to 100% height.  Otherwise to make it dynamic, you'll have to use javascript to calculate the height of the largest child.  Not a very elegant solution if you ask me.

If you provide more insight to the structure of your code, I can give you further suggestions of how to achieve your intended results the most efficient way.

Comment: Hi Axel, the desired solution has been found. Using the negative margin technique means I don't have to script anything :-)

Comment: You do realize that the solution you've chose here: http://jsfiddle.net/eW8yR/ causes the content of the "blue" div to go underneath the "yellow" div, right?  You can fix this by adding a child div with a padding-right of 110px (to make room for your sidebar).  Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eW8yR/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, then.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
     .cont{position:relative;}
     .col-a{
             border:1px solid #0000ff;
             width:auto;
             margin:0,110,0,0;
           } 
     .col-b{
             border:1px solid #ff0000;
             width:110px;
             float:right;
             top:0;
             position:absolute;
             margin:0,0,0,-110
     } 
</style> 
<div class="cont"> 
    <div class="col-a">Be flexible</div> 
    <div class="col-b">Be fixed</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is no good for me since my source order is important for screen reader purposes.

Comment: @spinners Edited to not re-order elements

Comment: @spinners Also, for readers, you can set the tabindex of the items in the order you want them to read. That should be compliant even on Divs.